# R run an oracle script file with multiple statements

Tags: r, oracle

I have a oracle sql script file with many individual queries in it as below. (The actual queries are much complex).

I want to read the file into R.

using glue, Convert the variables like temp1,temp2 to different values from R.

Execute the statements one by one.

```
"Create table {temp1};
Create table {temp2};
Create table {temp3};
insert into {temp1} values select * from {parenttable}"
```

I tried below

```
  filedata <- glue(read_file(file))
  statements <- filedata %>%
    strsplit(split = ";\n") %>%  unlist()

  walk(statements, ora_con)
```

The last `walk` statement doesnt seem to work. So how to use below statement iteratively? Or is there a better way to execute the script in one go after replacing the variables?

`dbSendStatement(ora_conn, singlequery)`

Answer (score 0):

If your sql script only had DML statements, I think you could just wrap it in `begin` and `end` and execute it as a single statement.  But because you have some `create table` statements in there, I don't think you can do that.  I'm not familiar with the `walk` function, but why not just use a `for` loop to execute each statement iteratively?

```
for(i in seq_len(length(statements))) {
  dbSendStatement(ora_con, statements[i])
}
```